# Selecting from MySQL as "checkpoints" onwards

Tags: mysql

I'm not sure how this is properly called, so I'll try to explain myself with an example:

Imagine on day 1.1.2013, you start attending school `X`. We enter this into a MySQL table, for example like this:

```
user | day      | school
1    | 1.1.2013 | X
```

Now, on 1.6.2013, you change school to `Y`. Let's enter this fact:

```
user | day      | school
1    | 1.1.2013 | X
1    | 1.6.2013 | Y
```

And again, for the third time, you switch schools:

```
user | day      | school
1    | 1.1.2013 | X
1    | 1.6.2013 | Y
1    | 4.3.2015 | Z
```

Now, **query**:

> What school were you attending on 1.3.2013?

The answer is: `X`

How do we write such query to MySQL to get the correct answer?

*Note:* The MySQL table structure can be different from what I presented if required.
*Note2:* This is **not** a homework assignment. This is a real situation I'm facing, but I haven't created my table yet, as I'm not sure what's the best solution so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make it properly store the 'day' column in DATE format - yyyy-mm-dd so you can sort it. and then run this. It will give you all days (actually only the most recent one, because of the LIMIT 1) in the past of the selected date, when the user signed in a school starting from the most recent one.

```
SELECT * FROM {table_name} WHERE day <= '2013-03-01' ORDER BY day DESC LIMIT 1
```

In your case you will get school **1** since **2013-01-01**

Edit:

in case your expediture table contains the date (in DATE format) you can use a subquery.

```
SELECT e.*, (SELECT school FROM {table_name} WHERE day <= e.date ORDER BY day DESC LIMIT 1) AS school_attended
FROM expenditures e;
```

If you provide the expeditures table scheme I can provide a better way probably.

Comment: That sounds great, but what about situations when you need to LEFT JOIN this to a different table, for example a table of your expenditures? You have a table of how much you paid for food **every day** and to every day, you need to LEFT JOIN the table of schools to know which school you were attending that day.

Comment: Let me correct my answer. It does not fit your needs the way it is now.